# OpenGL render state management

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm currently working on a small iPhone game, and am porting the 3d engine I've started to develop for the Mac to the iPhone. This is all going very well, and all functionality of the Mac engine is now present on the iPhone. The engine was by no means finished, but now at least I have basic resource management, a scene graph and a construction to easily animate and move objects around.

A screenshot of what I have now: http://emle.nl/forumpics/site/planes_grid.png. The little plane is a test object I've made several years ago for a game I was making then. It's not related to the game I'm developing now, but the 3d engine and its facilities are, of course.

Now, I've come to the topic of materials, the description of which textures, lights, etc belong to a renderable object. This means a lot of OpenGL clientstate and glEnable/glDisable calls for every object. What way would you suggest to minimise these state changes? 
Currently I'm sorting by material, since objects with the same material don't need any changes at all. I've created a class called RenderState that caches the current OpenGL state and only applies the members that are different when a different material is selected. Is this a workable solution, or will it grow beyond control when the engine matures and more and more state needs to be cached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of states in OpenGL ES as high as the standard version, it will be difficult to manage at some point.

Also, if you really want to minimize state changes you might need some kind of state-sorting concept, so that drawables with similar states are rendered together w/o needing a lot of glEnable/glDisable's between them. However, this might be sort of difficult to manage even on the PC hardware (imagine state-sorting thousands of drawables) and blindly changing the state might actually be cheaper, depending on the OpenGL implementation.

For a comparison, here's the approach taken by OpenSceneGraph:

Basically, every node in the scene graph has its own stateset which stores the material properties, states etc. The nice thing is that statesets can be shared by multiple nodes. This way, the rendering backend can just sort the drawables with respect to their stateset pointers (not the contents of the stateset!) and render nodes with same stateset together. This offers a nice trade-off since the backend is not bothered with managing individual opengl states, yet can achieve nearly minimal state changing, if the scenegraph is generated accordingly.

What I suggest, in your case is that you should do a lot of testing before sticking with a solution. Whatever you do, I'm sure that you will need some kind of abstraction to OpenGL states.

Answer (score 5):

A bit of advice. Just write the code you need for your game. Don't spend time writing a generalised rendering engine because it's more than likely you won't need it. If you end writing another game then extract the useful bits out into an engine at that point. This will be way quicker.

Comment: You have a point there. However, having at least a slightly generalized and optimized graphics engine will get me up to speed quickly for several ideas I have. The renderstate question, I think, is still valid however, because also game specific engines will have to do some renderstate management...